# Created a loop for multiple database and user creation in sql, but i am getting error

Tags: sql-server

Trying to create users with **domainame/username** with **windows authentication**.

database is getting created , but unable to create the user.

Could anyone please help me out.

This is the error:

> "Unknown object type '' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement."

Here is my Code :

```
  --BULK INSERT tempNames.dbo.tempNames
   --FROM 'C:\Users\Pruthvi\Videos\file.txt'
   --WITH 
     -- (
       -- ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
      --)

USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @NameCursor as CURSOR;
DECLARE @NAME AS NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @NAME2 AS NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @NIUNT AS NVARCHAR(50);

SET @NIUNT ='niunt.niu.edu\';

SET @NameCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT id
 FROM test.dbo.Sheet1$

OPEN @NameCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @NameCursor INTO @Name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @Name 
set @name2 ='create database '+@Name + ';'

  exec (@name2)

  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);


--  SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @NIUNT+ + @NAME + ' from windows';

    SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN' +@name+ 'WITH PASSWORD' +@name+ ';'




    exec(@SQL); 

    --EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = @name, @rolename = N'sysadmin';

    --SET @SQL = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @name + ' DISABLE';
    --EXECUTE(@SQL);
END;


 FETCH NEXT FROM @NameCursor INTO @Name;

 END 

GO
```

Comment: Can you provide the value of @SQL that is fed to EXEC function? It looks like one of the CRETE LOGIN statements is not ok.

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: could you please suggest me a better query to create user,I was trying to get domain_name/user_name in @SQl. and also assigning user to the database. Thanks in advance

Comment: I was getting error at SET @SQL line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing spaces  at the following line and your syntax is not correct:

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN' +@name+ 'WITH PASSWORD' +@name+ ';'
```

1.Add the missing spaces- change your query like this:

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' +@name + ' WITH PASSWORD ' +@name+ ';'
```

2.The correct way to set a Login in SQL Server is like this:(with a '=' sign)

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' +@name + ' WITH PASSWORD =''' +@name+ ''';'
```

Let's assume that your @name variable is 'test' your query will look like this:

```
SET @SQL ='CREATE LOGIN' +test+ 'WITH PASSWORD ' +test ';'
```

Results:

```
@SQL=CREATE LOGINtestWITH PASSWORDtest ';
```

So you are getting a "Unknown object type '' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement." error because sql doesn't recognize anything on this query.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I want to create user using domain_name/user_name using windows authentication , could you send me query for it.

Comment: @user2118497 First of, did my answer solved your error?

Comment: got an error, saying incorrect syntax near PASSWORD

Comment: SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' +@name + 'WITH PASSWORD ' +@name+ ';'

Answer (score 0):

> For windows your dynamic statement should be, as it contains an
>   special character \ :

```
 SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @NIUNT+ + @NAME + '] from windows;'
```

> For  SQL Server Authentication  :

```
   SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' +@name+ ' WITH PASSWORD=' +@name+ ';'
```

Comment: I tried that, but i was getting error like "Windows NT user or group '' not found. Check the name again'.

how to resolve it?

Comment: so are you sure user exits which you are trying to login. As this is not bound to syntax error

Comment: Thanks that issue was resolved. I am able to create login ... I am having another issue, I want to assign that user to a database, could you tell me how to do that in a loop